# Cloning Dual boot Ubuntu / Win 10 to new ssd

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, migration

My machine currently has one 256GB SSD with Windows 10 installed and 1TB HDD with Ubuntu 18.04 installed along with windows partition. My plan is to replace this 1TB HDD with the newly bought 1TB SSD.

I am curious whether there is an easy way to conduct the disk replacement.

Any help is appreciated!